# Why does the return data of a function useAsync appear undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-async

We tried to obtain weather data, but tried with the react-async library to determine the return value of this asynchronous function. However, the status is always displayed as pending and no data is defined.
Can you tell me why?

```js
// The parameter was omitted because the required values were obtained through other functions.
const weatherData = async () => {
  let req = await axios.get(getURLs(...getTime()).curr);
  let reqData = current(req);
  // console.log(req); 
  // console.log(reqData);
  return reqData;
};


// Component function
const WeatherList = () => {
  const { data, error, isLoading, promise } = useAsync({
    promiseFn: weatherData,
  });
  console.log(data); // undefined << Why are you doing this to me?
// ... more code
}
```

> react-async docs : https://docs.react-async.com/guide/async-components

Comment: Because the request hasn't been completed yet :) just ensure when you don't have data, return null, and once it's true, it will re-render and you'll have data

Comment: What your "current" function is doing to the request parameter ? What happen when you uncomment the console.log(req)?

Comment: Double-check the docs https://usehooks.com/useAsync/, `data` is undefined because you do not have an initial value set.